# Excess UITableView cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that seems to appear multiple times on my table before I even start scrolling.  It seems dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier isn't working properly.  Here's my cell:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    ... setup ...
}
```

When I call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: on my tableView, for some reason it doesn't dequeue that cell and it recreates the new one.  Then when I scroll back up and then down again, sometimes my first cell dequeues, sometimes the second cell dequeues.  MyCustomCell is basically a textfield so depending on which one dequeues, the text has different data each time.

Is there something more I should be doing in my custom cell?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the code that you're using to create the `CellIdentifier` variable?

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ccCell";

Comment: Your code seems ok. Is your UITableView sized properly? Maybe you're using an setup that makes the view thinks that you have a really tall table. You're not putting the UITableView inside a UIScrollView, are you? What version of the iOS SDK are you using? You shouldn't need to do anything else your your custom class.

Comment: Well, my custom cell has a custom contentview that basically has a UITextField that turns entered text into custom views.  Sometimes the custom views need to resize themselves so that's when I call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths to resize the tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you show, it looks as if you only set up your cell's content when a new one is created.  Since there's no way of knowing which cell you'll be given from the cache, you need to configure the cell whether it's new or one that's being re-used.

Comment: Correct. You create a new cell when dequeue returns nil, but you have to configure it to display the specified row/aection regardless of reuse or creation.

Answer (score 1):

You mention `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` in your question, but the method is actually `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.  The fact that the reload can be animated matters.   For example, to animate `UITableViewRowAnimationLeft`, the table view needs to slide out an old cell while sliding in a new cell.  Both the old and new cells are on screen simultaneously, so the table view can't just use the same `UITableViewCell` object for both.  That's why “it doesn't dequeue that cell and it recreates the new one”.  It needs a new one because the old one is still visible.

You need to make sure that when you receive a `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` message, you fully initialize the cell (whether dequeued or newly created) to show the data for the requested row, and *only* the data for the requested row.

Also, you can't keep your own mapping from the row's `indexPath` to the cell, because (during animations) there may be two cells for the same row.  Instead, if at any time you need to get the cell that is currently showing the data for a row, you need to ask the table view for the cell by sending it a `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` message.

Comment: @ rob mayoff I am using same method with animation UITableViewRowAnimationNone, even though it is creating a new cell for the first time. Why can't it will just use the same reusable cell like reload method?